# Tranverse an nested OrderedDict in python to locate a key and return it's value

Tags: python, optimization, collections, ordereddict

```
result = 
OrderedDict([('soap:Envelope',
          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:soap',
                        'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'),
                       ('@xmlns:xsi',
                        'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'),
                       ('@xmlns:xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),
                       ('soap:Body',
                        OrderedDict([('ServerJobResponse',
                                      OrderedDict([('@xmlns',
                                                    'http://www.goodexamplesfakesite.net/'),
                                                   ('ServerJobResult',
                                                    OrderedDict([('acXML',
                                                                  OrderedDict([('@payloadID',
                                                                                'a167f6e4-a57f-40b4-8a95-0d0f187b55db'),
                                                                               ('@xml:lang',
                                                                                'en-US'),
                                                                               ('@timestamp',
                                                                                '6/17/2021 '
                                                                                '1:38:03 '
                                                                                'PM'),
                                                                               ('@xmlns',
                                                                                ''),
                                                                               ('Response',
                                                                                OrderedDict([('Status',
                                                                                              OrderedDict([('@code',
                                                                                                            '200'),
                                                                                                           ('@text',
                                                                                                            'OK')]))]))]))]))]))]))]))])
```

My Attempt:

```
def foo(result):

    for k, v in result.items():
        if k == 'Status':
            return v['@code'], val['@text']
        elif isinstance(v, OrderedDict):
            return foo(v)
```

can someone suggest a better way, Please?

Comment: What issues are you having? It looks like your code should work.

Comment: @QuinnFreedman - Code does work. I am asking if the way I did is best possible solution?

Comment: "Best possible" is pretty subjective. If you are concerned about performance, you could take advantage of certain prior knowledge about the structure of the data or repleaded searches to optimize your approach. But if you don't know what the data is like going in you don't really have any option other than to search all of it.

Comment: @NullException [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this kind of questions.